# ImportError: No module named include.filename

Tags: python

I have the python 2.7 version and it was working fine when I do the `from include.trace_parse import *` but then I deleted .pyc files and it started throwing the following error.

```
from include.trace_parse import *
ImportError: No module named include.trace_parse
```

It works fine on python 3.

1. I deleted and created a new __ init__.py file
2. tried having project path in PYTHONPATH

Nothing worked. Not sure what could be the issue.

Comment: Could you create a minimal reproducible example for the community to work with? Also which package manager are you using? Do you have any virtual environments set up?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have folder named `include` and file named `trace_parse.py` inside it. You should place a `__init__.py` inside `include` folder then. `__init__.py` can be empty.

If your folder structure is like that

```
your_project folder
    main.py
        include
            __init__.py
            trace_parse.py
```

it should work.

For detailed guide, look for **relative imports** in python.